# MySQL/PHP Counting the top 3 most common values in a column

Tags: php, mysql

```
------------
| id | tid |
------------
| 1  | 0   | 2x 0
| 2  | 1   | 3x 1
| 3  | 3   | 3x 2
| 4  | 3   | 6x 3
| 5  | 3   | 1x 17
| 6  | 17  |
| 7  | 2   |
| 8  | 3   |
| 9  | 0   |
| 10 | 3   |
| 11 | 2   |
| 12 | 1   |
| 13 | 1   |
| 14 | 3   |
| 15 | 2   |
------------
```

Hello again stackoverflow!

I have the table as following. The table gets every few other minutes a number added. `id` is an `auto_increment` value and `tid` is the ID that gets added. `tid` can be any number starting from 0 and it can be in any order aswell.

I want to get the top 4 most common numbers in `tid`. For example, the top 3 here would be:

**1**. 3
**2**. 1
**3**. 2

But this is just an example.

How can I achieve this? Can I limit this to just use MySQL or do I need to use PHP aswell? If so what would I do and how?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tid, COUNT(tid) AS occurences
 FROM table
 GROUP BY tid
 ORDER BY occurences DESC
 LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total, tid 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY tid 
HAVING total>0 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 3
```